# MenuToggle won't show for responsive navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have done my research and so far I have tried just about everything. I am creating a responsive site with a slide push menu. I'm still learning Java and jQuery so I ended up creating it strictly through CSS coding. In order to do this I used:

```
  #menu-toggle:checked + .menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
        }
```

Then I applied the left property to my `.menu` with a value of -240px. However when I click on the menu button, the navigation bar refuses to show. On top of that it seems that my code editor does not recognize the `'transition'` property.

Here's a link to my `html` and `css` documents. This is for an academic homework.

I put my `responsive.css` in the JavaScript bin so that was no mistake.

http://jsbin.com/gerunayapo/1/edit?html,css,js

Comment: In your jsbin you has added a css code in javascript panel, do you have a demo url to view all context of your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. Is there any possible way for me to get one? Im willing to do anything at this point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do some mistakes like:

You add css in script panel in jsbin.

Then your write this wrong css:

```
#menu-toggle:checked + .menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Change it to:

```
#menuToggle:checked ~ .menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

There is `menuToggle` not `menu-toggle`. And use `~` instead of `+`.

Check [JS Bin link](http://jsbin.com/zisiwobada/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: OMG It worked! Thank you so much! I had no idea I had made such a trivial mistake! I really appreciate this! Thank you so much.